# convert a file to html in place

Tags: linux, vim

`TOHtml` could be used to convert a file to html, but it would also create a new file. For example, if the original file name is `test`, vim would create a new file called `test.html`.

Is there a method to modify the file in place, i.e. just convert `test` to html, and not create a new file?

Answer (score 4):

`:TOhtml` creates a new *buffer*. It does not save it, so it does not create a new *file*. You can exploit this fact:

```
" create test.html buffer
:TOhtml
" change back to test buffer
:b test
" destroy it, because we can't save another buffer with this name
" while this one is open
:bd
" switch back to test.html (if you had no other buffers, this is likely unnecessary)
:b test.html
" save it, overwriting the original
:w test
```

**EDIT:** I believe this is shorter while still doing the same:

```
:TOhtml
:bd test
:w test
```